# Installing plugins keeps failing because of es6-prepare-plugin

Tags: ios, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins

I am trying to prepare my iOS app and I need to get *socialsharing* and the *whitelist plugin* working, but they do not work. For example, when I do this:

```
sudo cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
```

I get this:

> Installing "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" for android
>
> Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing': 
>   CordovaError:
>
> Failed to fetch plugin es6-promise-plugin via registry. Probably this
>   is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect. Check
>   your connection and plugin name/version/URL. Error: npm: Command
>   failed with exit code 1 Error output: npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL npm ERR!
>   Could not install from "node_modules/es6-promise-plugin" as it does
>   not contain a package.json file.
>
> npm ERR!

**How can I fix this?** I tried everything. From sudo to non-sudo commands, but nothing is working for me. Adding *es6-prepare-plugin* manually does not work either.

My system information:

```
Cordova CLI: 7.0.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.8.1
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
```

PS: in my package.json file, I see this:

```
"es6-promise-plugin": "file:node_modules/es6-promise-plugin",
```

How can I change this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh dear Lord. I found the answer I was looking for, after I've struggled for hours. [This link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12061#issuecomment-309000315) on Github is the answer to this problem.

Seems like `npm` version 5.x.x does not work with some *ionic-plugins*. **I downgraded to npm 4** using `npm install -g npm@4.6.1` and installing this plugin worked for me afterwards.

Ionic is so buggy sometimes. Very annoying.